# ILogger and multiple threads -- add worker ID to log messages

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, dependency-injection

I just started a .NET Core console application for which I am relying on dependency injection. The logger is configured as singleton object. I can inject it just fine using `ILogger`.

The challenge I am facing is due to the fact that my application contains multiple workers doing the same work in parallel. So I am seeing messages from different components and different workers all together in one log file -- just sorted by date and time. This looks somewhat like:

```
Component1: Action1
Component1: Action1
Component2: Action1
Component1: Action2
Component2: Action1
Component2: Action2
Component2: Action3
Component1: Action1
Component1: Action3
```

I need to be able to track the actions of each worker. I see two ways wo accomplish this:

1. Let each worker use its own log file.
2. Add the worker ID to each log message

I prefer method 2 because it allows easier detection of (unwanted) dependencies and interferences between threads.

My program creates for each worker its own scope (and all created sub-components use the the same scope). So I thought it would be a good idea to create one (singleton) logger which actually writes to the log file. But the logger -- which is DI injected using `ILogger` -- is a scoped service. Only these scoped loggers use the singleton logger. Right after the worker scope is created, I would obtain the corresponding scoped logger and tell it the ID of the worker it is assigned to. This ID will be added to each log message before it is sent to the singleton logger.

My questions are: Is this approach feasible? Are there other (better? integrated?) ways to achieve what I am trying? Is there some completely other option which I missed?

Comment: This is already available. Whatever logging library you use, you can include the ThreadId in the output. Which library/sinks do you use? `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` is just the middleware, with few actual sinks.  It's up to the sink's configuration to include extra info. like the thread or process ID.

Comment: ^^ Serilog example: `var log = new LoggerConfiguration().Enrich.WithThreadId()`

Comment: @Fildor Serilog for the win

Comment: @00110001 :) It's just an example for a very popular framework. Most other logging systems would have some equivalent, I guess. ( I am not affiliated with Serilog )

Comment: `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` isn't trying to compete with Serilog or NLog, it's meant to provide an abstraction between applications and the logger. That's why there's no File sink and the built-in Console sink is limited. I think it doesn't emit the ThreadiD and at least until .NET Core 3.1 it doesn't allow customizing the message format.

Comment: The worker is using async/await. So the ThreadId can change at anytime. It is a (custom) worker ID I need.